# Persisting user/db object in PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, db2

I'm working on a web app, roughly using the MVC architecture outlined in the link below

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

I have created a custom class for logging in as described below. The user object is initialized in **index.php**. All requests are routed via **index.php** using **mod_rewrite**.

How can I make the user persist?

```
<?php

class user
{
    //connection setup
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';
    private $addressnumber = '';
    public $connection = false;
    private $host = '*LOCAL';
    private $options = array(
                'i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON,
                'i5_libl' => 'CLTSEC CLTPAY CLTDTA CLTCOM  QRY_FILES'
            );

    public function login($username,$password) {

        //check login variables not null
        if (isset($username) && isset($password)) { 
            //get form parameters
            $this->username= $username;
            $this->password= $password;
            $this->connection = db2_pconnect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->options);
            if (!$this->connection) {
                die('Could not connect');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //get addressnumber from username
                $sql='select F0092.ULAN8 from F0092 where ULUSER=\''.$this->username.'\'';
                $stmt= db2_prepare($this->connection,$sql);
                $result= db2_execute($stmt);
                while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
                    $this->addressnumber = $row['ULAN8'];
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    //disconnect from database
    function logout() {         
        db2_close($this->connection);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that object variables would not persist across pages. I needed a way to do this.

I have redesigned the class to make use of cookies for maintaining authentication between pages during  __construct. On successful authentication, properties are loaded from the database, instead of persisted in the session.